# Condition is Not checking properly in ng-if with !state.include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
     <select class="form-control"
     ng-if="((!$state.includes('home.allprojects') ||
     !$state.includes('home.Sentprojects')) &&
     !dynamicFields.isShowVismaButtons)" 
     ng-model="projects.selectedBokYear" ng-change="onBokYearChange()"
     ng-options="font.value for font in projects.bokYears"></select>
```

Here the code must display if the state is not in the home.allprojects or home.Sentprojects and !dynamicFields.isShowVismaButtons

ng-if="((!$state.includes('home.allprojects') || !$state.includes('home.Sentprojects')) && !dynamicFields.isShowVismaButtons)"

but the Select is visible even in the home.allprojects and home.Sentprojects state

can any one give a solution for it

Comment: I would suggest putting this whole `ng-if` code inside a function in your model

Comment: you cant access $state inside html

Comment: You can't access $state directly in HTML. Use any scope variable to store $state and try to access it from that variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748456/angular-js-ng-show-element-when-state-current-name-is-a-certain-value

Comment: Use this link might be there is condition issue also debug your value by putting inside {{ ((!$state.includes('home.allprojects') ||
   !$state.includes('home.Sentprojects')) &&
   !dynamicFields.isShowVismaButtons) }} in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cant access `$state` in html**,

Instead write a `function` which defines your logic and **call that function from your HTML**, or you can take a `variable` and use it in html for `state`

**I prefer going with a function which I added in my answer.**

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control"
ng-if="checkState()"
ng-model="projects.selectedBokYear" ng-change="onBokYearChange()"
ng-options="font.value for font in projects.bokYears"></select>
```

**In controller,**

```
$scope.checkState = function(){
    return ($state.includes('home.allprojects')) ||
           (!$state.includes('home.Sentprojects')) &&
           (!$scope.dynamicFields.isShowVismaButtons)
}
```

I have created a `checkState` function from HTML and defined your logic there.

Also, to check the state directly if there is no **parent-child**, you can use **`$state.current.name`**

```
$scope.checkState = function(){
return ($state.current.name != 'home.allprojects') ||
       ($state.current.name != 'home.Sentprojects') &&
       (!$scope.dynamicFields.isShowVismaButtons)
}
```

Comment: you may access  .run(function ($state,$rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
})

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748456/angular-js-ng-show-element-when-state-current-name-is-a-certain-value

Comment: @SantoshSingh, what you will do checking in `.run` function, we wants to change the html in current page depending on the condition. whats the reason to do that in `.run`?

Comment: It will allow accessing the $state in HTML not limited to scope only that is it if you will debug you will get the answer

Comment: where you seen $state accessing in `html`? I was never knowing that. Any reference?

Comment: using `rootscope` **doesnot give you a great performance**, and we need to check the state name everytime using `run` function.

Comment: I know but for him, it is the great answer! as he is new to angularjs

Comment: We should give him the solution that can be used as a future reference, even though he is new to angular, he should know, why we should not use `rootScope`. :-)

Comment: it will not make that much slower